# 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' when I send data from the Azure IoT hub to Azure Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I recive this error:

[23/3/2021, 12:53:24] Source 'outputstream' had 1 occurrences of kind 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' between processing times '2021-03-23T11:53:24.4853903Z' and '2021-03-23T11:53:24.4853903Z'.

in detail of the logs it tells me that it is a Date / Time problem that I have already tried to define both datetime and datetime2.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you try datetimeoffset in Azure SQL database table column?

Comment: yes i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @Jhonny Bonadiman, can you try using `nvarchar()` data type to receive the date data?

Comment: yes, but the error persists